# R function to evaluate expression over variable and create new variables filling in with logical

Tags: r

df1 (below) is an event log. variable 1 consists of (non-unique) timestamps (POSIXCt). Variables 2:4 consist of attributes of events (factors).

I've created df2 and df3 to define the time bins. df2 stores the initial time and df3 the end time for each time bin.

Question is how to expand df1 with the variable names of df2 (which are the same as df3) while filling in TRUE or FALSE for each event, based on wether the event belongs to one of the time bins of that variable.
In other words, if event belongs to time bin (as defined by df2 and df3) value is TRUE, otherwise FALSE.
Each event in df1 needs to be checked against all time bins (all pairs of elements of df2 and 3), one variable (of df2&3) at a time.

Due to the large number of variables and events, I cannot do this interactively.
But would like to learn how to do it the R way, avoiding explicit for loops, and taking advantage of vectorization.

DATA (small sampled datasets)

```
df1 <- data.frame(time.stamp = c("2015-01-05 15:00:00", "2015-01-05 15:01:00", "2015-01-05 15:02:00", "2015-01-05 15:02:00", "2015-01-05 15:03:00", "2015-01-05 15:03:00", "2015-01-05 15:03:00", "2015-01-05 15:03:00"),
                  g.id = as.factor(c("848", "737", "848", "848", "737", "848", "737", "737"))
              )
df1$time.stamp <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df1$time.stamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))                 

df2 <- data.frame(m0p1 = c("2015-01-05 15:00:00", "2015-01-05 16:00:00", "2015-01-05 17:00:00"),
              m1p1 = c("2015-01-05 15:01:00", "2015-01-05 16:01:00", "2015-01-05 17:01:00"),
              m2p1 = c("2015-01-05 15:02:00", "2015-01-05 16:02:00", "2015-01-05 17:02:00"),
              m3p1 = c("2015-01-05 15:03:00", "2015-01-05 16:03:00", "2015-01-05 17:03:00")
              )             
df2$m0p1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df2$m0p1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
df2$m1p1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df2$m1p1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) 
df2$m2p1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df2$m2p1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
df2$m3p1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df2$m3p1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

df3 <- data.frame(m0p1 = c("2015-01-05 15:01:00", "2015-01-05 16:01:00", "2015-01-05 17:01:00"),
                 m1p1 = c("2015-01-05 15:02:00", "2015-01-05 16:02:00", "2015-01-05 17:02:00"),
                 m2p1 = c("2015-01-05 15:03:00", "2015-01-05 16:03:00", "2015-01-05 17:03:00"),
                 m3p1 = c("2015-01-05 15:04:00", "2015-01-05 16:04:00", "2015-01-05 17:04:00")
              )
df3$m0p1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df3$m0p1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))  
df3$m1p1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df3$m1p1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) 
df3$m2p1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df3$m2p1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
df3$m3p1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df3$m3p1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

RESULT
The result would be something like this:

```
> head(df1.extended)
          time.stamp  g.id  m0p1   m1p1   m2p1   m3p1
1 2015-01-05 15:00:00  848  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2 2015-01-05 15:01:00  737  FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE 
3 2015-01-05 15:02:00  848  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   FALSE
4 2015-01-05 15:02:00  848  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   FALSE
5 2015-01-05 15:03:00  737  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
6 2015-01-05 15:03:00  848  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
7 2015-01-05 15:03:00  737  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
8 2015-01-05 15:03:00  848  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `foverlaps` from package data.table:

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df2, value.name = "start")
df3 <- melt(df3, value.name = "end")
df2$end <- df3$end

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[, time.stamp2 := time.stamp]

setkey(df2, start, end)
res <- df2[, foverlaps(df1, .SD, 
                by.x = c("time.stamp", "time.stamp2"),
                by.y = c("start", "end"),
                type = "start")[,list(time.stamp, g.id, match = !is.na(start))], 
    by = variable]
res[, id := seq_len(.N), by = variable]

dcast(res, id + time.stamp + g.id ~ variable, value.var = "match")
#   id          time.stamp g.id  m0p1  m1p1  m2p1  m3p1
# 1  1 2015-01-05 15:00:00  848  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 2  2 2015-01-05 15:01:00  737 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 3  3 2015-01-05 15:02:00  848 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 4  4 2015-01-05 15:02:00  848 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 5  5 2015-01-05 15:03:00  737 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 6  6 2015-01-05 15:03:00  848 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 7  7 2015-01-05 15:03:00  737 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 8  8 2015-01-05 15:03:00  737 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland. For the sake of good documentation I have fixed the expected output, as it had an imprecision, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: argument type = "start", as per example above, will not work as expected since the result is TRUE if a == c (TRUE is interval or value is equal to start time of reference interval). For identifying an interval (or a value) within the interval of reference, use: type == "within".